# How to reference mappers injected into a mapstruct mapper by the annotation "uses"

Tags: spring-boot, dependency-injection, mapstruct

I have defined a mapstruct interface, which makes use of two other mapstruct mappers:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = {Mapper1.class, Mapper2.class})
public interface ParentMapper{

}
```

Now I want to reference these two mappers inside my ParentMapper, i.e. I want to be able to access the concrete implementations `mapper1` and `mapper2`, as I need them in a default method I want to create. I was hoping to achieve this by injecting the mappers using @Autowired:

```
@Autowired
Mapper1 mapper1;

@Autowired
Mapper2 mapper2;
```

However, this does not work, because the mappers do not seem to be initialized. Since the mappers are injected by Spring, why would they not be initialized?

Answer (score 0):

Make your ParentMapper interface to be an abstract class and it will be able to use @Autowired feature.

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = {Mapper1.class, Mapper2.class})
public abstract class ParentMapper{
    @Autowired
    Mapper1 mapper1;

    @Autowired
    Mapper2 mapper2;
}
```

After this, you will be able to use default functions of mapper1 and mapper2.